# Problems with data binding in ItemContainerStyle in Silverlight 3

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, listbox

I'm unable to use data binding in the `ItemContainerStyle` for a `ListBox` in Silverlight 3. It works fine in WPF. This is contrived example to demonstrate my problem. What I really want to is bind to the `IsSelected` property, but I think that this example is easier to follow.

I have a `ListBox` that is bound to a `ObservableCollection<Item>` of `Item` objects:

```
public class Item {
  public String Name { get; }
  public Brush Color { get; }
}
```

Here is the relevant Silverlight XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The same XAML can be used in WPF if `TargetType="ListBoxItem"` is replaced with `TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"`.

The WPF application will display the items in the list box and set their background color according to the `Color` property of the `Item` object. However, the Silverlight application fails with and `XamlParseException` having the text `AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_UNKNOWN_ERROR`. Being a stubborn guy I Have even tried to remove the XAML that fails and created my own style instead like this:

```
  Binding binding = new Binding("Color");
  Setter setter = new Setter(ListBoxItem.BackgroundProperty, binding);
  Style style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
  style.Setters.Add(setter);
  listBox.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

If I try to run this I get an `ArgumentException` after my Silverlight control has initialized.

What am I doing wrong? How can I bind a property on the `ItemContainerStyle` to a property of the item?

Comment: Same as this bug? 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=356496

Comment: Looks like the same, but it was forwarded to the Silverlight team more than a year ago and still the fix didn't make it into Silverlight 3.

Comment: liversage - did you ever find a good way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK Silverlight (even 3) does not support bindings on style setters. You'd have to do some custom logic to alter the background colour when each item is loaded--probably by getting its parent in the visual tree, which would be the container, and setting it there.

Answer (score 0):

Your Item class isn't complete enough to tell, but Color is a Brush type and not a Color type right? Since the background property you're trying to set requires a brush.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add types to the properties of Item. Property Color has type Brush. I didn't include all my code to avoid writing a wall of text. However, I have a working sample that does the right thing in WPF and fails in Silverlight.